# Was classical BASIC ever used for commercial software development, and if so, how were limitations overcome?

Tags: history, basic

Many of us, including me, started their programming life with programs written on [home computers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_computer), something like

```
10 PRINT "ENTER RADIUS"
20 INPUT R
30 PRINT "CIRCUMFERENCE="; 2 * R * PI
40 PRINT "AGAIN?"
50 INPUT A$
60 IF A$="Y" THEN GOTO 10
70 END
```

Of course, the line-number based BASIC was prone for creating spagetti code, also because most BASIC dialects missed structural statements like `WHILE`, doing everything but the `FOR`-loop with `IF`, `GOTO` and `GOSUB`. I'm talking about BASIC dialects before 1991, when QBASIC and [Visual Basic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic) appeared.

While BASIC dialects may have promoted bad style amongst aspiring programmers, were there larger commercial projects created in such a BASIC dialect? If so, how did they manage to live with and workaround the obvious shortcomings?

By "serious", I mean:

- Not a game (I know some commercial games were written in BASIC, for example, [Pimania](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pimania))
- Not freeware
- Not trivial, that is, reasonably large (say: at least 1500 [LOC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_lines_of_code))
- Sold to several customers (not an in-house development)
- "Mission critical" is a plus

Comment: `Were those BASIC dialects only used to teach aspiring programmes bad style` Hm... It's bad style _now_ but it wasn't back then.

Comment: @YannisRizos: Structured Programming was invented in the early 70s, so I'd argue that in the late 70s/early 80s, when home computers (and therefore BASIC) became popular, they (makers of those computers) should have known better already.

Comment: Dartmough BASIC was designed in 1964 (and it was a compiled language, interestingly), an era dominated by FORTRAN.

Comment: Also Steve Garland added structured programming in BASIC sometime in the mid 70's, and off course there's always [SBASIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SBASIC).

Comment: Yes, it was used to teach bad style just like texting teaches poor spelling.

Comment: Assuming you are attempting to calculate the circumference of a circle, *style* is not the only bad thing I see here.

Comment: define serious programming? and define it in the context of an era. In the 80's lots of commercially viable software was written in BASIC on the early home computers.

Comment: If I could answer this, I'd point out that when the Apple ][ was king, a large percentage of its applications were written in BASIC.  I worked on a couple.  As to how we managed, well, first, when a language lacks structure, you use coding standard to give artificial structure.  Second, programs were small back then.  A BASIC program that would exhaust the machine's memory might be 30 printed pages.

Comment: ammoQ I'd vote to reopen if you specify "serious" as something like _standalone (to draw out interpreters) application that either has been sold over `1000` copies or has been among core components in `$100K` software project_. Side note in case if you're interested, a workaround for 1-month name change limitation is described [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45200/add-warning-when-changing-display-name "copy desired name from your other account")

Comment: @user281377 - the biggest problem I have with this question is the world "serious" in the title. Do you mean "commercial"?

Comment: `I'm seriously pissed off that this question was closed during the "History" contest.` Heh, you missed a great opportunity to get some extra views for the question by bringing it up on Meta.

Comment: The "not freeware" requirement is a bit messy, especially since BASIC already existed for ten years before the infamous ["Open Letter to Hobbyists"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Letter_to_Hobbyists). Even after that, freeware wasn't such a common term until the mid 80s.

Comment: 99% of all software that is written are **line of business** apps written **in house**, and by definition makes them about as **serious** as you can get.

Comment: @YannisRizos: I'm not too strict about the "not freeware" requirement; I just want to weed out hobby projects that could be used commercially, but nobody knows if that ever happened.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson: True, but since there is no lower limit for the quality of in-house-software, it would be unreasonable to assume that nobody ever used a VIC-20 running in-house-software to do something "serious", even is the program was as quirky as it can get. (Note: I'm not at all implying that all in-house-software is bad)

Comment: @user281377 I think there is no lower limit for the quality of commercial software, too. But I still like the limitation you introduced, although for a different reason: in-house references would be too hard to verify. _"Yeah I know 500K LOC BASIC app, mission critical and very successful. No - no further details - it is in house, trade secret, NDA, blah blah..."_

Comment: In the early and mid '70's a lot of commercial programming was done in BASIC on minicomputers (Data General, DEC, HP, et.al.) with terminals, or even teletypes, before the era of business PCs.  It was either that, or COBOL on far more expensive mainframes.  Entire businesses existed to serve this market.

Comment: @gnat: at least commercical software must be installable. Whenever a new customer comes buy, there must be a known way to install it. You cannot say the same thing about some of the worst in-house developed systems.

Comment: @user281377 can you imagine a product with a showstopper bug in installer? I can. For _commercial application_, "customers" could be guys who just paid money for what they read in marketing brochure, installation is not always an "ingredient" in that

Comment: @ChrisF Actually, one large answer could be made from all of the information in these comments. The only thing is, I think all of this info has already been mentioned in answers.

Comment: HP BusinessBasic on HP 3000 Mini, in 1970s, could well have had a 200KLOC BASIC app. But I doubt 500KLOC.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_3000

Comment: Have you tried rewriting your snippet in C (which has some pretty "serious" software to its name) and then talking about the limitations of BASIC? ;P

Comment: C sure has its own shortcomings, but it's definitely is much better suited for large projects than the kind of BASIC I asked about. BTW, the snipplet isn't here to demonstrate the weakness of BASIC, but to make sure people understand that I don't mean QuickBasic, VisualBasic or any other advanced BASIC dialect.

Comment: Nice to know the newer programming languages are so much more superior, so everyone can work on their social beer app.

Comment: I maintain about 100 different BASIC applications.  They are used every single day.  Have been used daily for almost 15 years.

Comment: Wasn't Staroffice originally written in BASIC?

Comment: (From Wikipedia)
"Sun Microsystems acquired the company, copyright and trademark of StarOffice in 1999 for US$73.5 million,[7] as it was supposedly cheaper than licensing Microsoft Office for 42,000 staff.[8]"

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Sure. Before the Altair/MITS/SWTPC/Kim/Sinclair/Pet/RadioScrap/OSI/Apple things happened, there was a delightful little machine known as the [IBM 5100](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_5100). It had BASIC in [ROM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-only_memory), a big cassette tape drive (or two), 8 KB of memory. a 24 line screen, and a printer, all for a measly USD 10,000 -- an order of magnitude cheaper than your typical mini. Originally built for scientists ([APL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_%28programming_language%29) in ROM was also an option), but then a few accounting types discovered it, and started a craze: every small business wanted one. With custom software, of course. The 5110 followed that, with the tape drives replaced by 8" floppies.

Any commercial software?  ***Galoons***.

Can you say general ledger, payroll, accounts payable, accounts receivable, inventory control, and invoicing?  I have been there, done that -- in BASIC.  Utility bills, new and used car inventory, garbage truck pickup and beverage delivery scheduling? Yup -- BASIC. Want to track [iron ore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_ore) from mines onto trains onto ships... BASIC. Everything that wasn't raised floor was likely getting done in BASIC. Commercially, I mean. (Because [RPG II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_RPG_II) doesn't count ;-).

How did one work around the limitations?

Well, the first thing you did was send the customer back to IBM for more memory, Because who could write anything serious in 8 KB? You simply *had* to have 16. And two tape drives, if possible, because automata theory aside, merge sorting on a single tape is, well, a tad slow.

Oh, sorry - you meant the limitations of BASIC.

Well, you had to manage your resources pretty carefully -- things like *line numbers* -- because you didn't want to run out of those; real pain in the behind to have to renumber a whole section, and type it all back in, without accidentally losing a line or two of code.

Nah - just kidding. We didn't actually have that problem until micro---er, home computers showed up, with a BASIC interpreter that couldn't do renumbering by itself.

We also used modularity - where you called a new program, ran it till it quit and returned back to the calling program. A gosub on steroids (because you got more memory to use), but way slower (because it took a while for the machine to find the program on the tape, and load it in, and then rewind and find the original program and load that back...). A lot like a fork and exec, but without the fork, only *better* because the whole memory space was shared.

Rigorous use of conventions also helped -- you know, like "you MUST always target a GOSUB at a comment line that says what this routine does, and you SHOULD do the same for a GOTO when possible. Stuff like that. Oh, and [structured programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_programming), a little later -- "by convention" again.

Some even went a little to the extreme: [OAOO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_software_development_philosophies#Miscellany), [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it), [TSTTCPW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it#Context), pairing, [refactor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring) mercilessly, that sort of stuff.  Not by those names, of course. (See also: Ecclesiastes ;-)

The glory days.

Comment: From all the good answers, I choose this one because it hasn't got too much love (upvotes) yet and also because it highlights the use of BASIC for commercial software on microcomputers before the rise of the homecomputers.

Comment: Up vote for your great answer and reference to one of the best books in the bible :)

Answer (score 47):

The first software I ever worked on was an 8k line GW-BASIC program that the company wrote back in the 80's to use heat transfer calculus for sizing and pricing boiler equipment.  While the code was completely incomprehensible, it managed to work so well that they had used it for over 20 years.

This was the strength of BASIC that a mechanical engineer with a reference manual could actually write quality usable software (at the time).  Before BASIC and the prevalence of the PC, such a thing would have been unheard of.  You would need to hire a team of computer engineers and possibly computer operators to program and work off of a shared mainframe.  All of this would have been far too complex for the typical mechanical engineer to pick up in a short amount of time.

So certainly BASIC was highly useful beyond home computer enthusiasts, this was many businesses first introduction into the realm of writing custom software inhouse for an affordable price without teams of experts.

Comment: Absolutely, this. --^^^

Answer (score 31):

Yes, there were numerous commercial products and other "serious" development done in BASIC.  To understand why, you have to understand the context of the 1970s and 1980s, when BASIC grew on mini- and microcomputers.

Back then, the machinery was positively scrawny by today's standards.  CPUs were clocked at a few MHz (often much less for microcomputers) and had less memory than would be occupied by the HTML it takes to render this page.  If you were going to deploy a product, you had to use the tools that were available, which was either bare-naked assembly or, on microcomputers, the BASIC interpreter that shipped in ROM (often 16K in a 64K address space) with the system.  There were other languages available, but many didn't have all of the structured features we take for granted.  This had a lot to do with the fact that memory was scarce,* none of it was virtual except on very-high-end systems and there usually wasn't enough of it to hold a compiler for a more-sophisticated language.  With such limited resources, "serious" was a relative term, and we simply weren't throwing the kinds of jobs at computers that we do now with plentiful processing, memory and storage.

Your argument that the makers of early home computers should have known better and provided a structured language just doesn't work in that context.  It simply wasn't going to happen with the available technology at a price people could stomach.

How we got around the language shortcomings was simple: we didn't see them that way and got the job done with what was available.  ANSI Minimal BASIC is structured a lot like assembly language in that you get most of the same flavors of simple branching and subroutine calls, but it's up to you to make sure the stars are properly aligned.  The sole exception is the `FOR..NEXT` construct used to provide looping.  Essentially, if you wanted to develop something in BASIC and do a good job of it, you had to plan out and understand the structure of your programs just as carefully as if you were writing them in assembly.  The available debugging tools were very primitive, so, in essence, *you had to have your act together if you wanted your programs to work and be maintainable.*

Yes, there was a lot of spaghetti back then, but I have yet to see a language where it's impossible to write bad code.

---

*Memory ran about US$750-1,000 per MB in the early 1980s.  Adjusted for inflation, that's US$1,600-2,200 in 2010 dollars.  That same year, the cost per megabyte was about US$0.03.

Comment: I remember paying about $1000 for a 2 **Megabyte** EMS memory board back in the 1980's. The computer it went in, a NEC V20 based PC clone kit, cost about $2500.

Comment: LOL, I remember we had to get a PO signed by the company president to buy a 64MB memory card for a VAX in the late 80s.  To be fair, it was dual-ported ECC memory, but it cost somewhere on the far side of $30K...

Comment: There were business applications written in BASIC, some of which sold for money, and a hot-selling business application written in BASIC, for APPLE ][ or CommodorePET, or Atari, or IBM, or TI microcomputers of the early 1980s might sell 100 to 500 copies, at about $100 unit prices. There was nothing like the modern software product back then because computers back then were small, and software for it was tiny. Neither basic nor C nor assembler nor any other modern language, would have changed that.

Comment: In the 80's our local colleges computer mainframe got an upgrade from 10mb to 50 mb.  Granted the 10mb was only half full but they wanted to have enough space for the forseeable future... Imagine that a hard drive with only 50 mb for about 50-100 users... being over kill.

Answer (score 23):

My first 100% programming job, back in the 1980s, was working on a vertical market accounting package that was originally written in [GW-BASIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GW-BASIC). It had been ported to [QuickBASIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QuickBASIC) 3.0, but it retained almost all of the faults associated with early BASIC dialects. There were tons of GOTOs and a lot of poor structure. There were about a dozen modules (inventory, ledger, etc.) and the program sold for about US$1000 - US$2500 per module plus annual support contracts. Company revenue was in the US$15 - US$25 million a year range.

As for how to live with shortcomings, a lot of limitations were gotten around by using machine language or [MASM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Macro_Assembler). It was common to use [PEEK and POKE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PEEK_and_POKE) commands to insert machine language into BASIC programs. I wrote MASM (and later C) programs to extend the program to add things like rudimentary database support, communications and text "graphics".

Comment: I pity you, unless of course, you got in on the 15 mil.

Comment: @SpencerRathbun - Sadly, I was paid a rather low wage, roughly equal to about $35K today.

Comment: Yup, my first programming job was in Quickbasic 3.  It wasn't a port but it wasn't much better.  The main part had been done by someone whose "training" was reading the book that came with the compiler.  Mission critical for customers, high 4 figure pricetag.

Answer (score 6):

Peachtree Software's entire accounting line (accounts receivable, payable, etc.) were all written (and still might be, for all I know) in BASIC.  When the IBM PC was first rolled out I spent many a long evening debugging and fixing their code for customers that bought an IBM Personal Computer and the Peachtree packages to do the books for their small business.

Answer (score 6):

My first job was in 1981 programming Apple IIs in Basic at a Price Waterhouse (Pre Coopers) office in their management consultancy in Belfast, N. Ireland. A team of two/three of us  developed and installed systems in clients including a bookshop and a slaughterhouse. It was a financial modelling system, effectively a very complex Visicalc spreadsheet (50 sheets, 3,000 variables) turned into a large Basic program. It took two days running on an Apple II system with 4 disk drives to process a week's throughput at the slaughterhouse. A bit quicker than their manual system that had taken two man weeks for each week.

We then moved onto Act Sirius machines, again programming in Basic (the Microsoft 8KB Basic) which were installed in clients.

The Basic had line numbers but there was a toolkit that could renumber programs. As I was fresh out of Uni where I had learnt Pascal, I tried to write in as structured style as possible (as much as you can in Basic), but Gotos and Gosubs were of course used.

I later programmed in 1983 on Dec Rainbow which used CBasic, a clunky compiled basic.

Answer (score 5):

There was a *lot* of commercial software written using [BASIC-PLUS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BASIC-PLUS) on the [PDP-11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDP-11) systems. I remember seeing statistical analysis and accounting packages, plus a fair amount of high-end laboratory automation stuff (I am not sure how "commercial" those were. They tended to be included as part of an instrument package, so I don't know if they were sold separately.). ISTR BASIC was one of the primary languages for [HP 2000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_2100) application development as well, and it was the primary (possibly only) language supported for their early [HP 9800-series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_9800_series) workstations.

Comment: Did the HP2000 support development in anything else?  My impression was that the HP2000 was hard-coded to *only* run user-supplied programs in HP Timeshare BASIC [some or all of the system's file-management and user-management code could have been written using other languages or machine code].

Answer (score 4):

> Were larger commercial projects created in such a BASIC dialect?

On older home computers like the C64 or its predecessors, there existed a lot of BASIC programs, and also some commercial ones. But "large" was seldom possible, since with <64kB of RAM writing "large" BASIC programs is not really easy. If you wanted to come around the limitations of the machine, you typically had to leave the ground of BASIC, the "high level language",  and use assembler.

So the answer to your question is "probably not many", but not because of the reasons you have in mind (like "too error prone / unstructured" etc).

By the way: AFAIK the famous PETSpeed BASIC compiler was written in BASIC (compiled with itself, of course).

Comment: I'd like to point out that important != large, especially back in those days. Today, commercial programs tend to have every imaginable feature built in, but that wasn't always the case.

Comment: @DocBrown There were ways to get around the 64k memory limit and large applications.  Many large applications existed more like app suites with many modules.

Comment: I remember several early commercial C64 games written either completely or partially in BASIC. 'Rox 64' is one.

Comment: "Telengard" I think it was called, an RPG game for the C64, was like 8k lines of Basic.  Was fun tweaking the source to make yourself an uber-character.

Comment: @maple_shaft: "Many?" Especially "Many BASIC applications?" I was under the impression there were only a few.

Comment: Thousands of games. Remember that the entire computer industry expected things to run in 48K, 16K or 64K of RAM.

Comment: @WarrenP: Thousands of larger commercial games, written in Basic? I doubt that.

Comment: In fairness, BASIC was essentially the operating system for a C64. And most of it was based around file operations, input and output. To do graphics, you had to almost PEEK and POKE the memory directly; to get a psuedo-random number, you had to read the next sound on the white-noise stream. C64 BASIC was pretty low-level, which is why Simons BASIC sold so well, despite its being useless unless both programmer and consumer had it (imagine trying to sell a game that required a $150 piece of hardware to run but had no added benefit for the user).

Answer (score 4):

Alpha Software's early DOS database products (circa 1985) "Database Manager I", "Database Manager II" (DMB2) and "Alpha Three" were written in BASIC and compiled with the IBM BASIC compiler.  I worked on "Alpha Three".  All the UI was in BASIC but it had a core TSR (terminate and stay resident) component written in C and ASM that the BASIC communicated with via interrupts.  Line numbers and line breaks took up valuable segment space so code was horribly squished and unreadable. We used shared variables and swapped modules constantly.  It was hard to make work. We still tried to be logical about organization however so our string library was all in the low 60000 line numbers.  A common operation like trimming a string would look like:

$S=$INS;GOSUB 60210;$INS=$S;

We converted to all C shortly after the release of "Alpha Three".

Comment: Since all variables were global, and you also had to abuse them for parameter passing, how did you manage your code to avoid accidentally overwriting an already used variable?

Comment: It was convention based.

Answer (score 4):

In the early 1980s the U.S. Air Force bought a bunch of [Cromemco S100 bus computers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cromemco) for use by flying squadrons as a flight planning tool.

The flight planning software was developed using BASIC by Air Force pilots and navigators at the Tactical Air Warfare Center, located at [Eglin AFB, Florida](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eglin_Air_Force_Base).

As far as working around the "the obvious shortcomings" of BASIC, we really didn't know any better. Just giving physical access to a computer to an aircrew seemed like an incredible leap of technology at the time.

Answer (score 3):

The only fear that I've had, as a QuickBasic programmer, 20 years ago, was "Out of memory" message. But this only made me a better programmer! I've learned how to write compact, and serious code.

I used to use QuickBasic for industrial programming. In the real world (factories) you cannot tell your boss "it's going to take half year to be written in C"; you can only say: "yes boss, it'll be ready next week". Yes, BASIC was the practical-and-quick solution in the real world. Not C or Pascal.

One of the programs I've written in QuickBasic 4.5, a unique database, was sold to few companies, and actually replaced the commercial database that they already had (which was probably written in C or Pascal). This database is in use until today.

One subject that I want to mention:

we all think that new programming methods are so much **useful**. But in the real life (industry), most machines, these days, are operated by modern PLC.
The programs are usually written in ladder programming, which is million times more primitive then GW-BASIC. 
As a programmer for PLCs I can say clearly: I would love to replace this primitive ladder programming with high level language as GW-BASIC or even QuickBasic. (MEGA-BASIC is a dialect that was used for this purpose in the past).

After all, what most machines are doing? interpreting inputs and setting outputs. You don't need C/Assembly for that, and you don't need Java. You surly need QuickBASIC to create a maintainable code.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the original Ultima on the Apple ][ was written in Applesoft Basic.

DEC used its version of BASIC for much of RSTS and other OSes it developed.

Comment: There was a joke that RSTS/E was written in BASIC, but it really wasn't.  Many sysadmin utility programs supplied with the OS were  written in BASIC though.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely yes.

Long long ago, I worked for a company that sold many million of dollars of systems, mainly to the auto dealer industry.  These systems ran BASIC software on customized 16-bit HP 21MX minicomputer derivatives (before the era of successful 16-bit microprocessors).  This was a medium size company with dozens of Basic programmers.  They used an old fashioned BASIC dialect which required line numbers and only allowed 286 possible variable names, and yet the solutions provided all the business accounting and inventory (etc.) for medium sized businesses.  The R&D group also wrote assemblers, compilers and even hardware emulators in Basic to help bootstrap development of their next generation hardware.

When attempting to explain what I thought were the benefits of more modern programming and hardware design methodologies to one old timer, he told me that good designers properly partitioned, modularized and structured the solutions to their problems, even if direct expression of such was not built into the language or tools, whereas, he noted, bad designers can produce un-debuggable garbage no matter what "fancy" fashionable development paradigm they work inside.

Answer (score 2):

Fact is,  most of the new car dealers in the U.S. today use BASIC programs to quote you financing options and to create those long settlement statements you get when you buy a car.  The programs are written in archaic minicomputer versions of BASIC running under emulation on modern hardware.  There are web UIs grafted on,  but its BASIC talking to a tty underneath.

Around 1980,  universal life insurance became an instant fad in the life insurance business.  Every company wanted to sell it right away,  and it required that account values be computed for each policy every month using a very complicated combination of interest and actuarial mumbo-jumbo.  As big projects in data-processing departments would take about a year back then,  many companies went into production with as many Apples, PCs, and/or Tandy TRS-80s as needed doing the more complicated version of what had been on mainframes for about 20 years.  Virtually all of these were programmed in BASIC. Mostly the BASIC used short-precision floating point,  so millions of customers' pennies got lost in the rounding.

JPL had a version of BASIC it used extensively back about 35 years ago, too.  It was called MBASIC, with the M standing for management,  but it was used, among other things,  to program spacecraft.

Answer (score 2):

IBM's hugely popular [4680/4690 retail point of sale system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_4690_OS) was written in a 
dialect called [IBM 4680 BASIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_4680_BASIC). I worked on this system from 1998-2002 for a major UK retailer.

This system was very popular, according to the wiki article it still held 12% of market share in 2005. The system is still going strong today, odds are good that most people in the western world have indirectly used this BASIC powered system in the last week.

Answer (score 1):

[BBC BASIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBC_BASIC) originated on the [BBC Micro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBC_Micro), released in the UK in 1981. By the time it reached version five, as implemented on Acorn's ARM-based RISC OS computers, it was considered the fastest interpreted BASIC in the world. Its syntax was advanced for its time, including structural keywords like CASE and WHILE and functions and procedures. (It even included an assembler, originally for [6502](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOS_Technology_6502), and then for ARM in the [RISC OS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RISC_OS) versions.)

Many commercial desktop applications were written using it, perhaps largely because it provided convenient access to the SWI calls that the cooperative WIMP system used. It was fast enough that there were even some arcade games written using it -- [Nevryon](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jOwhIlMoZZs), an R-Type clone, is one I particularly remember looking at the source of.

Comment: Actually, I had both an Acorn Electron (smaller version of the BBC) and an Acorn Archimedes (and also a Cambridge Z88 which used the same BASIC); and yes, the BASIC in these computers was a bit better than in most other home computers. But since the BASIC also included the possibility to use inline Assembler, it might be hard to distiguish pure BASIC programs from mixed programs if you just glance over the source code.

Comment: Oh, a quick glance really is all it takes to distinguish between the two. Very different-looking. And although it did include an assembler, it wasn't common to distribute assembly language source code. Usually the assembled binary code would be included instead.

Answer (score 1):

Look into PICK or any of the other MultiValue databases. They all rely on DataBasic as their main or only language and have a significant vertical market usage. We still run a system I wrote for procurement benchmarking over 20 years ago. Runs to about 50k lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

There was a company called Softek in India in the 80s that created their own versions of Wordstar, dBase and Lotus 1-2-3. Another of their products was a BASIC compiler.

Using their own CBASIC, they created a very comprehensive double entry accounting package called SIMS-FA (Softek Financial Accounting).

Answer (score 0):

Back in the days of the [Commmodore 64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commodore_64) part of the game [Gunship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gunship_%28video_game%29) was written in BASIC. You could even edit the code, so your helicoper could be equipped each time you landed.

Comment: I know some (commercial) games were completely written in Basic, but I excluded games for a reason: Games are whatever you make them, as long as they are funny. It's easier to live with the limitations when the "feature set" is completely up to the designer and maintenance is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

The old [xBase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XBase) database scripting languages (as in [dBase II](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBase#Ashton-Tate), [dBase III+](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBase#dBase_III), Clipper, etc.) were quite closely related to the various non-standard BASICs of the time.

Not exactly BASIC being used for commercial work, but maybe close enough.

Comment: Steve314: those xBase languages were far ahead of homecomputer BASIC. I wrote a lot of code in Clipper, and I remember functions, local variables, loop statements and a lot of other stuff that is missing in the home computer BASIC of the 80s. Yannis: QuickBasic appeared in 1985.

Comment: @user281377 - BBC Basic in 1981 was structured and had procedures, though it still needed line numbers. ANSI standard basic (1984) included block structures, `sub` (a function/procedure with parameters and local variables) and more, and made line numbers optional. Borland Turbo Basic in 1985 had most standard Basic features IIRC. I used GFA Basic on the Atari ST a fair bit - also structured, procedural, no line numbers. There were loads of structured, procedural Basics in the 80s.

Comment: @user281377 - xBase had obvious advantages in terms of database handling and data entry forms, doing things that no Basic did that I know of, but then you could just as easily point out that STOS had obvious advantages for displaying sprites and reading joysticks.

Comment: @Steve314: I know there were BASIC dialects with good features, but I'm specifically asking about the *other* BASICs. Those where GOTO and GOSUB were all you had. Where every variable was global and a one-dimensional array was as much data structure as you could possibly get. Clipper was a really advanced xBASE dialect; honestly, I can't remember how many of the advanced features of Clipper were available in dBASE III as well, but at least it had proper do-while loops.

Comment: @user281377 The original version of the answer was mentioning Visual Basic (where did you get QuickBasic from?), that was what I was screaming about ;P

Comment: @user281377 - OK, understood. BTW - dBase III+ definitely had do while loops, though I don't know for certain who copied from who.

Answer (score 0):

Any? Yes. Many? No. Educational software and record-keeping.

***The BASIC era: ~1970-1990***

Up until about 1990, limitations exceeded expectations and evolved with the industry needs. For the most part, needs of larger companies were analyzed by consultants and met with whatever language that fulfilled the need.

Rather like today, where companies have a more or less developed idea of what they need and have some sort of solution be built with VBA, and then learn enough to discover more competent client-server solutions, web apps, and optimized interfaces with data grooming.

In the 1970s, if a regular company could balance accounts or register production figures on the computer without the budget of a corporation, it would be a great step up from keeping books, and if you could get a diagram out, that was fantastic.

In the 1980s, if you could migrate some product drawings to the computer to make them editable, that would also be fantastic.

Both these could be done with an interpreter-based language. As computers could hold more data, complexity required compilers, because CPUs fell behind Moore's law in raw data shuffling performance from around 1977 to around 1987.

But up until the end of the 1980s when expectations demanded more, the languages established in the 1970s (complemented in rare cases by Assembler and/or custom hardware like FPU boards) did all the serious, commercial work in companies with few exceptions. Cobol and Fortran was the still the ticket on mainframes. Only corporations could afford such, and serious companies did what serious work they could with in-house BASIC programs, and for a while this was enough.

Standalone software packages for general use such as word processors or diagram plotters came along at around this time, when operating systems had matured on affordable computers as targets for compilers, and storage emerged that could hold "company size" documents and data.

Pascal was a major contender here. Previously, almost all such had been written in Assembler. Finally C came over from Unix and started being used on PCs.

Answer (score -2):

Most micros only had basic (ROM) or assembler development tools. For non-speed-critical programs BASIC was used for many commercial applications as well as most in-house company projects. Even when [CP/M](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CP/M) came along the only real enhancements were the ability to handle bigger projects and use Microsoft's basic compiler (BASCOM). My own experience with early micro development was as follows:

~1980 - Microsoft ROM basic on a [Nascom 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nascom) with a little assembler. Commercial application development included a [VAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value-added_tax) (sales tax) return program and a process control program (both in BASIC).

198? - Still using BASIC, but I now also had [Pascal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_%28programming_language%29) (BLS - precursor to [Borland Pascal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_Pascal)).

Mid 1980s - PCs begin to dominate and first C compilers appeared ([Hisoft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HiSoft_Systems) and Mix). BASIC goes into decline (revived later in zombie form of course by MS with [Visual Basic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic)). [GW-BASIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GW-BASIC) was very popular as an in-house development tool. Numerous commercial packages (accounting, stock control, etc.) was still written in BASIC.

Late 1980s - C becomes the main development language (after MSC 5 released 1986?). Microsoft and [Borland](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borland) dominate for next few years...

Comment: how does that answer the question?

Comment: it answers the question by saying 'yes, basic was widely used for commercial development in latest 70's and early 80's'. As regards overcoming obvious shortcomings, bear in mind that programmers did not see these shortcomings at the time. Basic is Turing complete so smart programmers could do anything they needed (main limitations were of course, speed, memory, storage etc but these limitations applied to all development at the time). Not sure why so many down-votes, was only trying to answer the question.

Comment: these two programs you mention, were these _Sold to several customers (not an in-house development)_? can you share references where one can learn more about these?

Comment: Unfortunatly many applications (including the ones I referred too) have been lost in the mists of time (no interweb or even BBSs to distribute to at the time). I have lost the cassettes on that these were stopred on but they were: 1) Not games, 2) not free, 3) Not trivial and 4) mission critical. I can't say they were sold to many customers, the contoal app was for specific customer, the VAT app was re-sold several times. Still peeved about down-votes (nit-pickers or shoud I say gnat pickers:-)).